# Fundamental solution for Helmholtz equation in higher dimensions

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, special-functions, greens-function, fundamental-solution

The fundamental solution for Helmholtz equation $(\Delta + k^2) u = -\delta$ is $e^{i k r}/r$ in 3d and $H_0^1(kr)$ in 2d (up to normalization constants).
Is there an explicit expression (eventually in terms of special functions) for the fundamental solution in dimension $\geq 4$? How can one derive it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We first assume that the point source is located at $\vec r'=0$, $\vec r'\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Spherical symmetry implies that the Green (or "Green's") Function, $G(\vec r|\vec r'=0)$, for the Helmholtz Equation can be written

$$\frac{\partial^2G}{\partial r^2}+\frac{n-1}{r}\frac{\partial G}{\partial r}+k^2G=0\tag 1$$

for $\vec r\ne 0$.

---

**FINDING A GENERAL SOLUTION TO $(1)$:**

Enforcing the substitution $G(\vec r|\vec r'=0)=r^{1-n/2}g(r)$ in $(1)$ reveals

$$r^2g''(r)+rg'(r)+\left((kr)^2-\left(\frac n2-1\right)^2\right)g(r)=0\tag 2$$

which is Bessel's Differential Equation (with argument scaled by $k$).  Solutions to $(2)$ are Bessel Functions of order $n/2-1$ and argument $kr$.

Therefore the general solution to $(1)$ can be written in terms of the first and second kind Hankel functions as

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{G(\vec r|\vec r'=0)=Ar^{1-n/2}H^{(2)}_{n/2-1}(kr)+Br^{1-n/2}H^{(1)}_{n/2-1}(kr)}\tag 3$$

In order for the Green Function to represent an outward travelling wave, either $A=0$ or $B=0$.  If the time convention is $e^{i\omega t}$ and $\text{Im}(k)<0$ in a medium with losses, then $B=0$.  If the time convention is $e^{-i\omega t}$ and $\text{Im}(k)>0$ in a medium with losses, then $A=0$.

---

**HOW TO DETERMINE $B$:**

To find $A$ or $B$, we apply the condition

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\oint_{r=\epsilon}\frac{\partial G}{\partial r}\,dS_{n-1}=-1\tag 4$$

where the integration is over the surface of the $n$-sphere of radius $\epsilon$.  The surface area of the $n$-sphere of radius $\epsilon$ is $S_{n-1}=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}\epsilon^{n-1}}{\Gamma(n/2)}$.

Using $(3)$ with $A=0$ in $(4)$ yields

$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\left(S_{n-1}B\left((1-n/2)\epsilon^{-n/2}H_{n/2-1}^{(1)}(k\epsilon)+k\epsilon^{1-n/2} H_{n/2-1}^{(1)'}(k\epsilon) \right)\right)=-1 \tag 5$$

---

**FINDING $B$ BY EVALUATING THE LIMIT IN $(5)$:**

To evaluate $(5)$, we use the small argument asymptotic approximation for the Hankel function and its derivative.  These are

$$\begin{align}H_{n/2-1}^{(1)}(k\epsilon)&\sim -i \frac{\Gamma(n/2-1)}{\pi}\left(\frac{2}{k\epsilon}\right)^{n/2-1} \tag 6\\\\
H_{n/2-1}^{(1)'}(k\epsilon)&\sim i \frac{(n/2-1)\Gamma(n/2-1)}{2\pi}\left(\frac{2}{k\epsilon}\right)^{n/2} \tag 7
\end{align}$$

Putting together $(5)$, $(6)$, and $(7)$ we find that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{B=\frac i4\left(\frac{k}{2\pi}\right)^{n/2-1}}\tag 8$$

---

**PUTTING IT ALL TOGETHER:**

Using $(8)$ in $(3)$ and setting $A=0$, we find that

$$G(\vec r|\vec r'=0)=\frac i4 \left(\frac{kr}{2\pi}\right)^{n/2-1}H_{n/2-1}^{(1)}(kr)$$

Finally, shifting the point source to $\vec r'$, we obtain the Green Function for the $n$-Dimensional Helmholtz Equation

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{G(\vec r|\vec r')=\frac i4 \left(\frac{k}{2\pi |\vec r-\vec r'|}\right)^{n/2-1}H_{n/2-1}^{(1)}(k|\vec r-\vec r'|)}\tag 9$$

---

**NOTES:**

For $n=2$, we recover the familiar $2$-Dimensional Green Function, $\frac i4 H_0^{(1)}(k|\vec r-\vec r'|)$, from $(9)$.

And for $n=3$, recalling that the $1/2$ order Hankel Function is related to the Spherical Bessel Function, we recover the familiar $3$-Dimensional Green Function $\frac{e^{-ik|\vec r-\vec r'|}}{4\pi|\vec r-\vec r'|}$ from $(9)$.

Comment: An answer of amazing quality. Did you have also a trick in mind to obtain the same result with Fourier transform? I got stuck trying to find the inverse Fourier transform of $1/(|\vec{r}|^2 - k^2).$

Comment: Thank you!  I'm pleased that this was useful.  This solution took me a while - believe it or not, I kept making careless arithmetic errors in determining $B$.  To apply the $n$-dimensional FT, the "trick" is to move the singularity off of the real axis by introducing a "small" imaginary part to $k$.

Comment: This really is a good answer. Out of curiosity: Do you think the same analysis applies to the operator $-\Delta_k^2$? It should give an exponentially decaying fundamental solution in this case.

Comment: Also: Does anyone know any literature on this?

Comment: @frank Just replace $k$ with $ik$ to find the aolution to $\nabla^2 G-k^2G=-\delta(\vec r)$.  And I have not been able to find any references on this.   I searched the internet but was unsuccessful.  If you find something, please let me know.  -Mark

Comment: @Frank Well, you're incorrect on both accounts.  First, for $n=3$ and $k\to ik$, we have from $(9)$

$$G(\vec r |\vec r')=\sqrt{\frac kr}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}K_{1/2}(k|\vec r-\vec r'|)\tag{C1}$$Furthermore, Bessel functions of order $n+1/2$ are related to the spherical Bessel functions [SEE THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Spherical_Bessel_functions:_jn.2C_yn).  In this case, $(C1)$ becomes

$$G(\vec r |\vec r')=\frac{e^{-k|\vec r-\vec r'|}}{4\pi|\vec r-\vec r'|}\tag{C1}$$as expected!  So, your analysis is flawed.

Comment: You're absolutely coorect. That's really neat, actually: It is known that the Bessel potential $$G_2(x) = (4\pi)^{-n/2} \int_0^\infty t^{-n/2} e^{-t-|x|^2/4t}\,dt$$ (which is derived via Fourier analysis) is the fundamental solution for $-\Delta+1$. And in fact, one has $G_2(x) = (2\pi)^{-n/2}x^{1-n/2}K_{n/2-1}(x)$, which exactly ties in with your analysis.

Comment: @frank And there you have it.  -Mark

Comment: Great answer! You have saved me a lot of headaches. I don't quite get how $A$ and $B$ are obtained. First, do you have any references about the Hankel functions corresponding to the travelling waves? Also, if I apply Green's identity I get (formally) $$\int_{r=\epsilon}\partial_\rho G = \int_{r\leq\epsilon}\Delta G = \int_{r\leq\epsilon}\delta_0-\int_{r\leq\epsilon}\lambda G = 1 - \int_{r\leq\epsilon}\lambda G.$$
Could you please correct me where I'm wrong? Thank you

Comment: Thank you!  The Divergence Theorem does not apply here because of the singularity of $G$ and its derivatives at $\vec r=0$.

Comment: @MarkViola I see, but then where does the condition $$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\oint_{r=\epsilon}\frac{\partial G}{\partial r}\,dS_{n-1}=-1$$ come from?

Comment: This condition accounts (equivalently) for the Dirac Delta in the Helmholtz equation.

Comment: That's what I supposed, but when I tried to hand-wave it, I got the discrepancy that I exposed above. Thank you for pointing out the flaw.

Comment: What I have done now is use the definition of distributional derivatives: for any $\phi\in C_0^\infty,$
$$-\phi(0)=\langle-\delta_0,\phi\rangle=\langle(\Delta+\lambda)u,\phi\rangle\equiv\langle u,(\Delta+\lambda)\phi\rangle,$$
and then integrate in $\{\epsilon\leq r\leq R\}$ with $\epsilon\to0$ and $R\to\infty$. Then using Green's identity in this domain I get
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_{r=\epsilon}\partial_r u\,\phi=-\phi(0).$$
My guess is, just take a $\phi$ that is constant around $0$ and we have the necessary condition. Is it right?
P.S.: Sorry for being such a pain.

Comment: @Frank Fundamental solutions for the $n$-dimensional Helmholtz operator are derived in Chapter 9 of [McLean's book](https://books.google.at/books?id=RILqjEeMfK0C&lpg=PP1&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)